# Phonegap offline storage

Tags: iphone, directory, cordova, documents

I'm working on a phonegap iPhone app which downloads content from the network in the form of HTML docs with text, images, and embeded HTML5 videos.

I want to download these documents as they're available and store them locally, for further reading in offline mode. I've searched a bit and found that the optimal place to store this kind of data would be in the app's **Documents** folder. However, I don't really know how to access it with the Phonegap API.

I know how to create an XHTML file from js, but how do I read/write files from/to my own app's Documents folder?

Comment: If only there was a way to access a photo from the device's browser cache - that would save you having to manage it yourself...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can store the in the sqlite database provided by the browser.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html

Comment: A whole XHTML page on a database field?

Comment: You can use the file io.  http://phonegap.pbworks.com/JavaScript-API#file 

But some people have mentioned better performance with the database

Comment: Thanks a lot for both links. They were vere helpful.

Comment: The most up-to-date info for Phonegap dbs is here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't store the video data in a database.
Also in web sql there is a 50MB limit for the entire database in IOS.
I would use the PhoneGap File API to hook into the filesystem http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Also consider encrypting the videos by writing an objective c plugin or using something like RNCryptor https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor